# xpath to get values of an element where one is an array

Tags: xpath

```
          <a:Foo>
            <a:Value1>42</a:Value1>
            <a:Value2>bil jac</a:Value2>
            <a:Bar>corner-bar-and-grill</a:ClientKey>
            <a:MyArray>
               <a:MyArrayElement>
                 <a:ValueA>string 1</a:ValueA>
                 <a:ValueB>string 2</a:ValueB>
               </a:MyArrayElement>
            </a:MyArray>
          </a:Foo>
```

Above is my xml

<a:Foo> an array element

The path to it is

<s:Envelope><s:Body><a:Array1>

I need an xpath expression to give me <a:Value1>, <a:Value2> and all <a:ValueA> elements in all <a:Foo> elements

This

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/Element1/Array1/a:Foo[a:Bar/text()='corner-bar-and-grill']/*[self::a:Value1 or self::a:Value2]
```

give me Value1 and Value2

This

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/Element1/Array1/a:Foo[a:Bar/text()='corner-bar-and-grill']/*/*[self::a:MyArray]//a:MyArrayElement//a:ValueA
```

gives me ValueA from the array

How do I combine the 2 into one single command?

Comment: `expr1 | expr2` if the language in use implements the union operator (pipe)

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0 you can use the union operator at the outermost level:

```
a/b/c/d/e | a/b/c/d/f
```

In XPath 2.0+ you can use the union operator within an individual step:

```
a/b/c/d/(e|f)
```

With XPath questions, please always say which version you are using, since many people are using very old versions.